# Microsoft Graph Webhooks subscription on /users - not usable in current format

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

So having been to Ignite in 2017 I was really excited with the new possibilites the Webhooks in Microsoft Graph and binding to Azure functions.

Recently I got the chance to really explore this for myself. 
I am looking at this from the perspective of Identity Management - I really want to see what kind of user onboarding/change management we can react to and process with Graph Webhooks and Azure functions. So I started looking at the beta endpoint and the Webhooks available for "/users"

The first thing that struck me was that in the beta only "updated" or "deleted" is a valid changetype. I really would like "created" - since that is when the most work would get done on a user (for example generating some unique attribute values)

Ok I thought and just tried looking at "/users" and only changetype="updated". I created a subscription and an basic Azure function to handle the requests. Updated a user in Azure AD (just changed "Last name" attribute) and sure enough a trigger was sent to my Azure function

Now comes my biggest problems - this is really unusable in its current form.

1. his seems to react to the all changes /users and i guess the trigger response could contain several users.
   It really would be preferable to get individual triggers for each object changed in /users even though they were changed at the same time
2. Looking at the actual information sent here lies the BIG problem. 
   I get the id of the user changed (good, but also expected)
   I get the organizationId (ok..)
   I get the eventTime (good)
   I get a sequenceNumber (unsure what this is?)
   I get subscriptionExpirationDateTime (ok fine good to have)
   I get subscriptionId for the webhook (ok fine good to have)

... but WHERE is information about what data was changed??? Nowhere to be found is what attributes of the user were changed (i my case "Last name"). This makes the triggers totally unusable for "/users" and I cant really think of anyone who could use this function as is? 
Sure I know the object was changed but I have no idea WHAT happened and if the change was relevant to my function

Please tell me there are plans to include the actual changes in the trigger response?

EDIT: ok right, yeah this is more a feature request from the actual developers of ms graph - will look for a better place to get this answered

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Stack Overflow is a community site for developers helping developers. This isn't a suitable forum for feature requests, opinions, or roadmap discussions.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide feature requests here (ex: richer data in notifications, "created" change type) : https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=101632

Here are answers to other questions.

1. Microsoft graph doesn't guarantee ordering of events when sending notifications (ex: your webhook endpoint could be down and we will retry events delayed by up to 4 hours or drop if the outage is longer than 4 hours). Hence "SequenceNumber" can be used to track if an event is in order and hence used as is or if it is out of order and needs a query to Graph to get current state.
2. Currently, we provide Ids of objects and associations (member, manager) that have changed, whether the object/associations is deleted or updated but not details of other properties that were changed. In its current form, webhook is best used with delta query. Instead of polling delta query every X minutes and in most cases receiving zero changes, developers can create a subscription and perform delta query only when a notification is received. This would help scale in case there are many tenants that needs to be polled.

Delta Query: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_overview

Also FYI, webhook notifications for user/group is now also available in V1.0